# How to return back to my app home screen from get direction activity?

Tags: android, dictionary, google-glass

In my app i have put 2 button,first button show different location name and second different location name.When i click on one of them then i call get direction from my app like that

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=48.649469,-2.02579"));
startActivity(intent);
```

When i rich that location and i swipe down from glass then google glass not show my app home screen they show ok glass screen.

How to show home screen of my app when user swipe down from get direction in place of ok glass screen ?

Thank you...

Otherwise How I can open Map in my app. within app.

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this problem out? I'm trying to figure out the same thing.